# Nexus Maven proxy error "Prefix file entry count exceeds maximum allowed count (10000)"

Tags: nexus, nexus2

My Nexus version is 2.5.1-01. I have added Central repository (http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/), but the Routing tab shows below error message

```
Remote strategy prefix-file detected invalid input, results discarded: Prefix file entry count exceeds maximum allowed count (10000), refusing to load it.
```

I found that this was a known issue https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-10233
But the mentioned workaround didn't work for me. Could it be because of my nexus version that provided workaround is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible, 2.5.1 was released in 2013 (3 years before the fix to NEXUS-10233).  Highly recommend upgrading, it'd fix the issue if that's the issue you have anyway.

Ref: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM2/Download+Archives+-+Repository+Manager+OSS

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I upgraded to 2.14 and now it works.